# Filtering SOQL results with optional conditionals

Tags: soql, filters

I am creating a web component that allows users to filter the results of some data based on some optional filtering fields. In SOQL, how do you handle returning results when a filter is not set?

For example, I have a `Student__c` object. I want users to be able to filter by the the Student__c's `Field A` (String), `Field B` (Integer) and `Field C` (String).

I have this function:

```
function getStudents(nationality, school, birthYear) {
    return [SELECT * FROM Student__c WHERE ....];
}
```

I call this function to load some data to display in a graph to a user. The user doesn't have to filter the students by `nationality`, `school`, and `birthYear`, so by default, these values will be null, and should return the results of all students. But if the user opts to filter by `birthYear`, then it should filter by birthYear. If they want to filter by birthYear and school, then it should do so.

I'm trying to avoid having to do something like:

```
function getStudents(nationality, school, birthYear) {
    if (nationality == null && school == null, && birthYear == null) {
        return [SELECT * FROM Student__c];
    } else if (nationality != null && school == null, && birthYear == null) 
        return [SELECT * FROM Student__c WHERE nationality__c == :nationality];
    }
    else if ( .... ) {
        ...
}
```

Instead of having different queries for the different scenarios (3 field filters is 8 different queries, 4 fields is 15 different, etc.) I would like my query to handle it all. I was thinking about using a contains, but SOQL doesn't have that from what I believe...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to apply Dynamic SOQL. Here's one way to approach it.

Start with a query template string, with placeholders for your dynamic entries:

```
String queryTemplate = 'SELECT [your list of fields] FROM Student__c {1} {2}';
```

We'll dynamically construct the content of the `WHERE` clause based on data. We'll use an extra merge field to allow us to cope with the possibility that no filters are provided at all, and we don't need a `WHERE` clause.

Next, we would build up a list of `WHERE` subclauses based on the passed information. For example, you might have something like this:

```
List<String> whereClauses = new List<String>();

if (nationality != null) {
    whereClauses.add('Nationality__c = :nationality');
}
if (school != null) {
    whereClauses.add('School__c = :school');
}
if (birthYear != null) {
    whereClauses.add('Birth_Year__c = :birthYear');
}
```

Then, once the list is complete, we can construct a final query and issue it dynamically:

```
return Database.query(
    String.format(
        queryTemplate,
        new List<String> {
            whereClauses.size() > 0 ? 'WHERE' : '',
            String.join(whereClauses, ' OR ')
        }
    )
);
```

This keeps your logic flat, and avoids the combinatorial madness of trying to account for every possible combination of input parameters. It also - provided you issue the query in the same method or scope where you construct it - allows you to use Apex binds, so you avoid having to worry about type conversion and SOQL injection defense.

I like to go so far as to dynamically construct my `SELECT` clause too, from a `List<Schema.SobjectField>`. That way, my code retains a static, compile-time reference to the field, and I get proper metadata dependency tracking. It also streamlines enforcement of FLS.

Comment: Awesome! So if everything is null, the WHERE clause won't create an issue? Because if everything was null, wouldn't the query string end up being `'SELECT ... FROM Student__c WHERE ';`

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, @BlondeSwan. Let me slightly amend my answer to cover the case where no filters are provided.